# Why Internet download manager doesn't come up in this page?

Tags: html5-video, idm

I noticed that IDM (internet download manager) does not come up in this page when the video starts playing: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

the code behind this page is a simple html5 video tag:

```
  <video id="video1" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls>
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
```

When I use the exact same code with the same video in localhost, IDM starts. I have no special setting or exclusions in IDM. So what is the secret behind this page that IDM is not starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some videos  are protected by Copyright and use special protected protocol. It is restricted to save any data recived by this protocol. IDM does not support it for legal reasons.([Reference](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/video11.html))

To check that this is the reason why video is not shown, you need to open "Options->General" IDM dialog and press "Edit" near "Customize IDM Download panels in browsers".

[image: IDM Download panels]

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean from special protocol? HTTPS or special video protocols? I have downloaded the exact video and tested it on localhost (with http) but the IDM comes up.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com is maybe can use a private video hosting services. Like this one:  [PRIVATE AND SECURE VIDEO STREAMING](https://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/video-protection-video-privacy.html)
This services for prevent  video downloading tools. (Like IDM)
More information you can read this article:
[How to Protect Your Videos from Being Downloaded](https://foliovision.com/player/securing-your-video/protecting-video-from-downloading)